# How to skip multiple validation ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 forms.

Form 1 I have 10 fields which I am validating.

Form 2 but it only contains 2 fields.

The model is same.

What I need to do is:

To validate fields when they are submitted by forms. If I am not posting any fields it should not validate in model. If I post 5 fields it should validate 5 fields. If I post 2 fields it should validate only 2 not all of them.

So form 1 all 10 should be validated, form 2 only 2 should validate not rest of 8.

Here is my code:

```
validates :teacher_number, :title, :name, :gender, :location, :dob,
:contact_mobile, :contact_home, :street, :city, :state, :zip_code, :country, 
presence: true
validates :teacher_number, uniqueness: {scope: :school_id}
validate  :teacher_number_existance, :on => :create
validate  :school_existance, :on => :create
```

Below is my attempt which successfully works fine but its bulk of code that somewhat a bad practice.

```
 validates :teacher_number, presence: true, if: "teacher_number && teacher_number.blank?"
  validates :title, presence: true, if: "title && title.blank?"
  validates :name, presence: true, if: "name && name.blank?"
  validates :gender, presence: true, if: "gender && gender.blank?"
  validates :location, presence: true, if: "location && location.blank?"
  validates :dob, presence: true, if: "dob && dob.blank?"
  validates :contact_mobile, presence: true, if: "contact_mobile && contact_mobile.blank?"
  validates :contact_home, presence: true, if: "contact_home && contact_home.blank?"
  validates :street, presence: true, if: "street && street.blank?"
  validates :city, presence: true, if: "city && city.blank?"
  validates :state, presence: true, if: "state && state.blank?"
  validates :zip_code, presence: true, if: "zip_code && zip_code.blank?"
  validates :country, presence: true, if: "country && country.blank?"
  validates :teacher_number, uniqueness: {scope: :school_id}, if: "teacher_number && teacher_number.blank?"
  validate  :teacher_number_existance, :on => :create, if: "self.teacher_number && self.teacher_number.blank?"
  validate  :school_existance, :on => :create, if: "self.teacher_number && self.teacher_number.blank?"
```

**EDIT**

**UPDATED MY QUESTION.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after so going back and forth below solution worked well for me.

```
before_validation :strip_validations

def strip_validations
     ['teacher_number', 'title', 'name', 'gender', 'location', 'dob', 'contact_mobile', 'contact_home', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'country'].each do |attr|
     errors.add("Teacher", {attr => " #{attr} can't be blank"}) if send(attr.to_sym) && send(attr.to_sym).blank?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways for this:

1. Some hidden param in form and `attr_accesor` in model to turn off validation.
2. Use `save(validate: false)` for save from that second form.
3. Next, you can do it like this

   `if validate_object?
       validates :email, presence: true
       validates :variant, presence: true
     end`
4. You can use some patterns like [form object](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/158-form-objects-in-rails).

But you have to remember that this object will be invalid in future too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not my case. Hidden params do exists in my case with keyword, `teacher` or `personal_teacher`

Answer (score 0):

If you want different validations of data in different circumstances, you should not be validating on the model. You should validate elsewhere: either in the view using [HTML form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation), or in the controller using Rails' [Strong Params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

I think you should use HTML form validation to manage this, because you're worried about the record *missing* attributes. Strong Params is more useful in case you are worried about people supplying *forbidden* values for record attributes.

Here is how you would use HTML form validation to manage this (example using HAML):

```
= form_for @model do |f|
  = f.text_input(:teacher_number, required: true)
  ...all your other inputs...
  = f.submit 'Submit Form'
```

Here is how you would use Strong Params to constrain the number of things you can get:

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  def form_action_1
    Model.create(form_1_params)
  end

  def form_action_2
    Model.create(form_2_params)
  end

  private

  def form_1_params
    # let's permit all the things you want for the first form
    params.require(:model).permit(:teacher_number, :title, ...)
  end

  def form_2_params
    # let's permit only the few things you want in the second form
    params.require(:model).permit(:only, :a, :few, :things)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for in detail reply but now a days people do hack form by inspecting forms and remove required fields :) Also when people will do that, it will crash everything in terms of security :) I am checking both thing means in forms i have required and in model i have validations. A safety check :D Problem is I am unable to use them when needed :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but perhaps this approach would work. Write your validations like this:

```
validates :teacher_number,
  :title,
  :name,
  :gender,
  :location,
  :dob,
  :contact_mobile,
  :contact_home,
  :street,
  :city,
  :state,
  :zip_code,
  :country, 
  presence: true,
  on: :form2
validates :teacher_number, uniqueness: {scope: :school_id}
validate  :teacher_number_existance, :on => :create
validate  :school_existance, :on => :create
```

The `on: :form2` near the bottom of the first validator means the validations will only run if you explicitly ask them to run.

So in your controller action for saving form2, you would have to do this:

```
if valid?(:form2) && @model.save
```

The other validators will run when you save, as normal. Using the `on:` parameter of `validates` for your own symbols (as opposed to the built-in ones) is covered in the Rails Guide for validations, but it's easy to miss. I didn't notice it myself until recently. I hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow you got it right way. Let me explain you. Say, I have form 1 with 10 fields and form 2 with 2 fields. upon submitting form 2 it says your 8 other fields are empty and fill them in. I want to bypass all these 8 validations for form 2. What do you say? I have no create method in controller. Any idea?

Comment: Updated my question